# bash copy the first file form source folder to destination folder

Tags: linux, bash

I am using mac os. I am in a situation that I need to copy the only first file private key which ends with `_sk` to another directory. Please any suggestion would help me.

Comment: Note: default sort order will be influenced by your LOCALE setting, so it may differ from install to install. When you say first -- how do you get first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop over the files ending with `_sk` and break the loop after copying the first file. If that's really the "first file" you wanted to copy is another question.

```
for i in /path/to/source/*_sk; do cp "$i" /path/to/destination/; break; done
```